# Creating and cloning repository not working

Tags: git

So the commands I ran were...

```
machineA> git init --bare repo.git
machineB> git clone bob@machineA:/srv/git/repo.git
```

Error message I get...

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /opt/tempGit/randomstuff/.git/
fatal: '/srv/git/repo.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I have never created a git repository before but by the tutorials online it seems correct. All the other repositories on the server I am able to clone from the same machine (I've setup public key authentication), it's just this new repository that I am unable to clone (I must be missing a step).

Any help would be appreciated cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to create a normal repository.

```
git init repo
```

When you go to clone the repository, you would add the `--bare` flag.

```
git clone --bare bob@machineA:/srv/git/repo.git
```

Comment: OP wanted the bare on machineA, the non-bare on machineB.

Answer (score 0):

It appears it was a file permissions issue. I did a good old 'chmod -R 777 /srv/git/repo.git' and it seemed to fix the issue. Obviously you shouldn't use 777 as your permission, but it seemed to be a good test case to if it worked.

Cheers